# Issue with Checkbox and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I do have a checkbox list and when you click on one of them it should be update the page via AJAX

```
$(document).on("click", ".selectlist input", update_results);
```

So my client asked me to make one of those "checked" by default.
basically you can do it with this code

```
   $('input#my_id').prop('checked', true);
```

But the thing is the AJAX will be work just when you click on the item.
Is there anyway either change the AJAX to when input is checked not click or make the checkbox clicked onLoad?

Thanks

Comment: `$('input#my_id').click();` ?

Comment: @FelixKling Doesn't update the page, Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to copy my full code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').trigger('click');
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9z8panbn/

Comment: Can i use the combination from my AJAX and your code so it should say trigger click on input and then update_results?

Comment: `.trigger('click')` will trigger a click event on the selector, in this case the `input`. So if you have declared previously in you code bindings like `$(document).on("click", "input", update_results);` they will trigger as well (the `update_results` function will be called). Here's the [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) functionality documentation.

Comment: I guess `$('.selectlist input#tbs-service-0').trigger('click' );` should be into your `document.ready` scope not outside

Comment: @Amir: Yes it seems like you are triggering the click before the event handler is bound.

Comment: @FelixKling and iceless i put in inside the document.ready and before the update_result code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Amir: Same problem: *"it seems like you are triggering the click before the event handler is bound"*. You have to trigger the event **after** you bound the event handler. Isn't it obvious that the handler can only be triggered if it is bound at the moment the event is occurring?

Comment: @FelixKling Ah sorry, i was misunderstood. Working great! Thanks both